# document.getElementById sometimes null despite using window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I am having an issue where document.getElementById is sometimes (one time in 10-20) returning null despite using window.onload. My relevant code is below.

ptp.html:

```
<body>
    <div msa-include-html="msa.html"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="msa.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        includeHTML();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            initForm("urlAction");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

msa.html:

```
<form id="msa" method="get">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="input" />
    <p id="output"></p>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

msa.js:

```
includeHTML = function (cb) {
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("msa-include-html");
        if (file) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    elmnt.removeAttribute("msa-include-html");
                    includeHTML(cb);
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (cb) cb();
};

function initForm(urlAction) {
    document.getElementById("msa").action = urlAction;
    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", updateOutput);        
}

function updateOutput() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var output = Number((1 / 3 * input).toFixed(0));
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output.toLocaleString();
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `includeHTML()` function performs an **asynchronous** operation to fetch content. The function will return after *starting* that operation, but the fetch will finish *after* your other code expects the content it loads to be present in the DOM.

The line

```
if (cb) cb();
```

should be inside the XHR callback, not outside as you've got it now. As it stands now, the callback will be invoked before the HTTP request completes. Your code only works when the content is in the browser cache, I suspect.